# Синонімічне словосполучення до "відповідати вимогам"

Tags: фразеологізми, синоніми

Виникла потреба підібрати синонімічне словосполучення до **`відповідати вимогам`**, щоб уникнути тавтології у вислові **`відповідь відповідає вимогам`**.

Наразі є такі варіанти:

**`відповідь задовольняє вимогам`**

[Задовольняти](http://sum.in.ua/s/zadovoljnjaty)

і менш вдалий

**`відповідь має ознаки відповідності вимогам`**

[Відповідність](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidpovidnistj)

**Є якісь милозвучніші варіанти?**

**UPD**. Стаття СУМ на слово **`відповідність`** підказала ще один варіант:

**`відповідь узгоджується з вимогами`**

**Але інші вдалі варіанти вітаються, бо доводиться в тексті декілька разів застосовувати таке формулювання, і дуже бажано уникати потвторів.**

Comment: "відповідь має ознаки відповідності вимогам" - мені здається що це щось на кшталт "на перший погляд відповідає вимогам (має ознаки), але треба ще розбиратися". Так пишуть у поліцейських рапортах "купюра має ознаки підробки", "має ознаки втручання", але ще треба це довести.

Comment: @Artemix, погоджуюсь. Може бути контекстуальним синонімічним висловом. Та я й зазначила, що не досить вдалий варіант.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> <sup>[Академічний тлумачний словник](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidkhodyty) [(1970—1980)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85)</sup>
>   **ПІДХОДИТИ**, джу, диш, *недок.*, **ПІДІЙТИ**, дійду, дійдеш, *док*.
>
> **6.** Бути [придатним](http://sum.in.ua/s/prydatnyj), [прийнятним](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryjnjatnyj), відповідаючи яким-небудь вимогам. *Цей нарис цілком буде підходити до другого томика* (Михайло Коцюбинський, III, 1956, 213); *Вона говорила.., що місце не підходить дитині і не такі їй потрібні цяцьки* (Олесь Гончар, Тронка, 1963, 308); *Не знаю, чи вподобається Вам [«День у дорозі»] і чи підійде до Вашого збірника* (Панас Мирний, V, 1965, 386); *Приходь [на весілля] не з порожніми руками: неси сороківку,.. часничину чи бублик на закуску. Таранька теж підійшла б* (Юрій Смолич, Мир... 1958, 39);
>
> **/**  Бути відповідним кому-, чому-небудь. *Вона вгадувала своїм жіночим серцем, що Харитін підходить під її завзятущий, дужий темперамент* (Нечуй-Левицький, III, 1956, 37); *До далеких звуків пісні так підходила ця проста, злита з природою бесіда* (Гнат Хоткевич, I, 1966, 90);
>
> **/**  [Личити](http://sum.in.ua/s/lychyty) кому-небудь. *Туристка.. знала, що ця блузка їй дуже підходить* (Михайло Томчаній, Готель.., 1960, 6); *[Настя:] Ніби риза [халат], золотом вишито. Як би це нашому батюшці підійшло* (Олександр Корнійчук, II, 1956, 114);
>
> **/**  [Пристосовуючись](http://sum.in.ua/s/prystosovuvatysja) до когось, чогось, [підроблятися](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidrobljatysja). *Він і сяк і так підходив під кріпаків* (Панас Мирний, IV, 1955, 204); *Вона вхопила пляшку й бурхнула й собі рому в .. стакан, щоб підійти під смак Гануша* (Нечуй-Левицький, III, 1956, 220).
>
> ♦ **Не підходити під плече** — не бути рівнею кому-небудь. *[Козубська:] Ніколи хам панові під плече не підійде!* (Марко Кропивницький, II, 1958, 235).

Ось такі словосполучення, якщо враховувати приклади зі словника й обмежитися словом „вимога“

> *… се оповідання, котре вповні [підходить під вимоги](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%22&tbm=bks) конкурсу як по своєму об'єму …*
>
> *… "мікрокультура" маскулінності в повсякденному житті дуже добре [підходить до вимог](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%22&tbm=bks) націоналізму …*

Comment: Сформулюйте, будь ласка, ваш варіант(и) усього словосполучення.